# Prove that this is one-one, but not onto $\Bbb R$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$\Bbb R$ stands for real numbers.

> $ f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> 2-x,  & \text{if $x \le 1 \qquad \text{is one to one but not onto } \Bbb R $  } \\
> \frac{1}{x} , & \text{if $x >1$ } 
> \end{cases}$

I know how to prove that this is one to one by saying that an element in the domain maps too exactly one element in the range set.

$x\le1 \;\Rightarrow \; f(x) = f(y) \Rightarrow \; 2-x =2-y \Rightarrow x=y$

$x>1\Rightarrow$ $\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{y} \Rightarrow x=y$

We can say from this that this is one-one. I am having trouble understanding why this is not onto. I know that $0 \notin \Bbb x$.  This is where I get lost. I know that a function is onto if every element in the range set has a preimage is the domain set. I am just not too sure what that means in applying to this problem.

Comment: For example, it is I think easy to see that there is no $x$ such that $f(x)=-10$.  By the way, your one-to-one is incomplete. You also need to check there is no $x$ and $y$ with $x\le 1$ and $y\gt 1$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: The mapping $f\colon?\to ?$ is defined by $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
2-x,  & \text{if $x \le 1$}\\
\frac{1}{x} , & \text{if $x >1$ } 
\end{cases}$$
Those question marks become important. Presumably they are $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$, but are they?

Comment: "I know that $0\notin\mathbb{R}$". This is not correct. Did you mean that $0$ is not in the image of $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $0\notin f(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: What I mean is that $0 \notin x$

Comment: What do you mean by $0\not\in x$?

Comment: What does $0\notin x$ mean? Isn't $x$ being used in your question to denote a real number rather than a set?

Comment: I thought it would be undefined therefore it $x \neq 0.$

Comment: What would be undefined? The function? The function can be evaluated at zero: since $0\leq 1$, $f(0)=2-0=2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not onto because the value of the function is always above zero. Thus, for example, $0\in\mathbb{R}$ but there is no $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=0$.

To elaborate on Andre's comment, you need to add this to complete your proof that $f$ is one-to-one: For any $x\leq 1$ and $y>1$, $$f(x)=2-x\geq 1>\frac{1}{y}=f(y).$$

Comment: Thanks. I misread the function. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

In showing this is one-to-one, you should also consider the case where $x>1$ and $y\le 1$ and show that in *that* case you cannot have $f(x)=f(y)$.  What you've done takes care of the case where both are $>1$ or both are $\le 1$.

It's not onto $\mathbb R$ because no value of this function is negative or $0$.

Comment: It cannot be all real numbers in other words it is not onto.